# Lock Pages in Memory, button disabled

Tags: windows-server-2008

Windows Server 2008. It's not a domain controller. My user is in admin group. UAC is disabled.

I'm trying to configure Lock Pages in Memory, but find that button "Add User or Group" is disabled, why could be that?

[image]

**Edit:**

On the Start menu, I clicked Run. In the Open box, typed gpedit.msc. Button is still disabled:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That means it is enforced by Group Policy.

Comment: In that case, I couldn't change configuration of Lock Pages in Memory?

Comment: You can - by using Group Policy Management Console and editing the policy that is specifying the setting, or creating a new policy for that computer.

Comment: Nope. On the Start menu, I clicked Run. In the Open box, typed gpedit.msc. See my addings at my question. Button is still disabled.

Comment: You're editing the local policy on the server. The setting is being enforced by a Domain policy. Run `RSOP.msc` to see which policy is enforcing the setting.